# OpenCV function to merge Mat's except for black/transparent pixels

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `Mat` containing text with a black background and a Mat containing a background. I want to merge the 2 Mat's so the text sits ontop of the background. Both Mats are BGR (CV_8UC3) and the same size (cols and rows).

Whats the OpenCV way of doing this?

I'm aware of a couple of functions but `|=` and `+=` are changing the text colour and `addWeighted()` only works if I want one image to be slightly transparent. I just want to do a complete merge of the two (except not the black pixels in the text image). I'm looking for an OpenCV function rather than pixel editting myself, well a `LUT` would be good if thats an option.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sourceText = yourTextImage;
sourceBackground = yourBackgroundImage;

cv::Mat textTransparent;
cv::inRange(sourceText, cv::Scalar(0,0,0), cv::Scalar(0,0,0), textTransparent);
cv::imshow("transparent pixel", textTransparent); // this should show all the transparent pixel as being white. If that's not the case, adjust the range.
std::cout << "is the transparency mask ok? Press any key with openCV window focus." << std::endl;

cv::Mat result = sourceBackground.clone();
sourceText.copyTo(sourceBackground, 255-textTransparent); // copy pixels, using the created mask.
```

instead you could copy the transparent pixels from the sourceBackground to the sourceText which is a bit faster because you don't need the 255-textTransparent...

Could not test the code, please tell me if there are bugs.

Comment: Ah... a few minutes late... too bad... I have already prepared the [images](http://imgur.com/a/OOI3q) to answer this.. :( (feel free to use them ;D)

Comment: @Micka, do you think using `threshold(textImg, mask, 1, 255, THRESH_BINARY); textImg.copyTo(bkImg, mask);` would be faster?

Comment: @Merl , might be possible. Not sure whether threshold works for color images. Probably there is some way to do it faster than inRange.

Comment: You could try with `textImg.copyTo(bkImg, textImg != 0)`. However, that will copy only the *channels* that are not zero. Which means that if your text image is only blue, it will keep the green and red channels of the background when copying.